# Azure mainTemplate.json - access output from templateLink

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have a JSON deployment template with something like:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
    "name": "parameters('storageAccounts')[copyIndex()].name",
    "resourceGroup": "[resourceGroup().name]",
    "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
            "uri": "'https://foo.blob.sa/StorageAccount/azuredeploy.json"
        },
        "parameters": {
            ...
        }
    },
```

`azuredeploy.json` creates the storage account then has something like:

```
"outputs": {
    "storageAccountWebEndpoint": {
        "type": "object",
        "value": {
            "tags": { ... },
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[reference(parameters('storageAccountName')).primaryEndpoints.web]"
        }
    },
```

Is it possible to leverage the output from the linked template to set a property for another resource in my deployment template?
If so, what would be the syntax?

*(Assume I have `dependsOn` set correctly.)*

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `reference()` to get the output in the link template:

```
"[reference('deploymentName').outputs.propertyName.value]"
```

But note that:

> When getting an output property from a linked template, the property
> name must not include a dash.

Get more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell#get-values-from-linked-template).

Comment: It took me a while to figure out the deploymentName, but I found out they used a function to create it. This is  what ended up with this working:


"[reference(deploymentResource.name(parameters('storageAccounts')[copyIndex()].name, 'StorageAccount')).outputs.storageAccountWebEndpoint.value.value]"